# Losing timestamp information when copying hive table

Tags: hive, timestamp

I work with a very large data source and am trying to create a small subset table to test my code on to make development quicker. I'm working with data that contains high frequency data (1-100Hz) so timestamp precision down to the microsecond is important for my work. However, after creating the new table querying it, the year, month, and day are the only bits of the timestamp that are copied over and the hour, minute, second, and microsecond values are all 0. My first attempt was a simple, eg:

```
create table database.table_name as select * from source_database.source_table;
```

I've also tried creating the table with a schema to explicitly declare the column of interest as a timestamp type and then insert the data into it but I got the same thing. Eg:

```
create table database.table_name (val1 int, val2 string, val3 timestamp); 

insert into table database.table_name select val1, val2, timestamp(val3) from source_database.source_table;
```

I also tried to cast the timestamp as a string but the problem persisted. I feel like there's something simple I'm missing but I'm relatively inexperienced when it comes to creating tables in hive so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How original strings look like?

Comment: When I query the source table and cast as a string, it's the normal timestamp format. However, when I cast it as a string when inserting into the subset table and then query it, it's the same, just without the hour, minute, second, and microsecond precision (all zeroes).

Comment: why do you cast timestamp to timestamp?? timestamp(val3) please provide some examples

Comment: It was out of desperation. The main issue is that I don't know why I would lose precision with just a `create table database.table_name as select * from src_db.src_tbl;`. I'm trying to see if I can solve the root cause of it or at least find a workaround.